# Admob mediation earnings

Tags: android, admob

I may risk an off-topic but I don't know a better place to ask:

When using the mediation in Admob, the earning from the other networks are transferred to the admob account or each network has its own account?

If they have their own account it may last very long to get to the amount of pay out.

thank You.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, each network usually have their own account. And yes, it can take a very long time to get the money out. At least that's what I've read on blogs when I did my research. I think a network might not survive if word got out that they didn't pay out the earnings so... the truth might lie somewhere between.

Personally I like the question because I had a very hard time to find good info. And many times it's us developers who set everything up.